# OpenModelica Script issue about setParameterValue

Tags: scripting, openmodelica

I've using script files to do my simulation. I use omc.exe to run my mos file.

**I've been facing with 1 issues**:

```
loadModel(Modelica); getErrorString();
loadFile("C:/Users/namcho/Documents/Tez_DAB/Simulation/MachineLearningAlgo/DAB_ideal.mo"); getErrorString();
loadFile("C:/Users/namcho/Documents/Tez_DAB/Simulation/MachineLearningAlgo/uControllerDAB.mo"); getErrorString();
checkModel(DAB_ideal);
Kp := 1.2;
Ti := 5e-5;
Td := 0;
typeOf(v1);

setParameterValue(DAB_ideal, PID_Kp, Kp); getErrorString();
setParameterValue(DAB_ideal, PID_Ti, Ti); getErrorString();
setParameterValue(DAB_ideal, PID_Td, Td); getErrorString();

instantiateModel(DAB_ideal);
```

In the code above I want to pass Kp's value to my DAB_ideal model. If I try as above it gives

> "[C:/Users/namcho/Documents/Tez_DAB/Simulation/MachineLearningAlgo/DAB_ideal.mo:3:3-3:20:writable]
>   Error: Variable Kp not found in scope DAB_ideal. Error: Error occurred
>   while flattening model DAB_ideal"

that error.
**If I try setParameterValue(DAB_ideal, PID_Kp, 1.2); it works.**
How can I pass that Kp's value to setParameterValue function? I've tried PowerShell $ symbol(and a couple more different symbols) to pass the Kp's($Kp) value to the function it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work yet as only values or parameters found in the models can be used as the third argument. The setParameterValue function doesn't care what expression you give, it will put it in the model as a binding. I will see if we can implement a quick solution for this, it should be rather easy to have a function call such as $VariableValue(Kp) which we can replace by the actual value when passing it to the model. I will open a ticket about this.